# Time-independent Schrödinger equation. Explicit solution

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, mathematics, differential-equations

I have seen so many times this partial differrential equation like this:
$$\frac{\partial ^2 y}{\partial x ^ 2}  =- \omega^2y $$
has solution $$y = A \sin(wx) + B \cos(wx)$$

similarly: $$\frac{\partial ^2 y}{\partial x ^ 2}  = \omega^2 y$$
has solution: $$y= Ae^{\omega x}+Be^{-\omega x} $$.

We can check that the solution is right but I tried to solve this differential equation explicitly. I am not able to do it. Can anyone show how can we solve these differential equations explicitly? Or any reference.

Comment: This question would be more at home on [MathSE](https://math.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this particular case, you can proceed directly as follows. Define a new variable $z=\frac{dy}{dx}$. Then you can write

$$\frac{d^{2}y}{dx^{2}} = z\frac{dz}{dy} = w^{2}y$$

which can be solved easily

$$z^{2} = w^{2}y^{2} + c$$

$c$ is the integration constant. Choosing the positive root for now

$$z = \frac{dy}{dx} = \sqrt{w^{2}y^{2} + c}$$
$$\frac{dy}{\sqrt{w^{2}y^{2} + c}} = dx$$

The integral on LHS can be solved using the substitution $y=\sqrt{c}\sinh(\eta)/w$. This gives

$$y = \frac{\sqrt{c}}{w}\sinh(w(x+d))$$

d is another integration constant. This can be written in terms of $\sinh wx$ and $\cosh wx$. Substituting, $w\rightarrow{iw}$ you get the harmonic oscillator case and the solutions become $\sin$ and $\cos$.

Answer (score 2):

The solutions of these equations are obtained with the general methods for solving [linear ordinary differential equations with constant coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation#Homogeneous_equation_with_constant_coefficients). It seems from your question that you are not familiar with these methods, so I wonder how you could try to solve them... You either need to learn the necessary methods or simply trust the given solutions.